# What is the error in my CS50P jar.py class exercise?

Tags: python, class, cs50

The assignment is to create a class of "cookie jar" that can hold 0-12 cookies. Unfortunately I keep getting one error on the Check50, but I can't figure out why.

```
:( Jar's constructor raises ValueError when called with negative capacity
    expected exit code 0, not 1. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.
```

```
class Jar:
    def __init__(self, capacity=12):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.size = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return '' * self.size

    def deposit(self, n):
        self.size += n
        if self.size > 12:
            raise ValueError('Too many')

    def withdraw(self, n):
        self.size -= n
        if self.size < 0:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Capacity')

    @property
    def capacity(self):
        return (self._capacity)

    @property
    def size(self):
        return (self._size)

    @capacity.setter
    def capacity(self,capacity):
        self._capacity = capacity

    @size.setter
    def size(self,size):
        self._size = size
```

I have searched extensively and I am confused because a value greater than 12 is set up just like less than 0, but I am getting different Check50 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, capacity=12):
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.size = 0

def deposit(self, n):
    self.size += n
    if self.size > 12:
        raise ValueError('Too many')
```

I think you've misunderstood these two functions.

I imagine that `__init__` is supposed to raise an error if the initial capacity is less than zero (or, realistically, less than one, because what good is a jar that can't hold any cookies at all?), or greater than twelve.  But your function does not validate the value at all.

And in `deposit`, you should not check if the number of cookies is greater than 12; you should check if it is greater than `self.capacity`, because this cookie jar might have a capacity less than 12.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Totally agree with the self.capacity issue - I felt weird putting 12 there, should have followed my instinct.  Fixing that alone still gave me the same error.

Comment: I thought about where to put the over 12 and under 0 (agree with your 1 thought though!), but I followed the instructions (I think) on the CS50 page. "deposit should add n cookies to the cookie jar. If adding that many would exceed the cookie jar’s capacity, though, deposit should instead raise a ValueError. withdraw should remove n cookies from the cookie jar. If there aren’t that many cookies in the cookie jar, though, withdraw should instead raise a ValueError." I did move both checks to __init__ (just to see) but it caused me to not pass for greater than 12 as well.

Comment: You should have the checks in all three places.  init, deposit, and withdraw.

Comment: Bingo! I apologize if this is too simple, but why do I have to do it in both locations? I know __init__ initializes the class, but do I also have to do the checks there in the event deposit or withdraw are not called (since they won't always be called)?

Comment: I should have said, in all 3 locations.

Comment: `__init__` defines the initial capacity, and you want to ensure that capacity is within reasonable limits, so you need a check there.  If the user wants to add cookies, you must ensure that they don't overflow the jar, so `deposit` needs to check too.  And the same applies when they want to take cookies out -- you must ensure that they don't withdraw more cookies than exist in the jar, so `withdraw` also needs to check.

Answer (score 0):

I think your should use self._capacity or self._size at those lines
[lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA5Zf.png)